# Preview: Change the Fill option for the Annotate tool

Tags: macos, preview

I enabled the annotate option on the Tools for Mac Preview Application and now I cannot draw a rectangle without the Fill option. How can I get rid of the Fill option so that I can draw a rectangle without filling the contents in it.

Here is the example of a filled rectangle in it.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fill colour is in the same toolbar, see pic…

*[Edit - updating for Yosemite, Mavericks is below…)*

Yosemite -

1. Show Toolbar
2. Fill drop-menu
3. Transparent is the one with the red line through, top left of the colour-picker.

[image]

Mavericks -

1. Rectangle tool.
2. Fill colour
3. Transparent is the one with the red line through, top left of the colour-picker.

[image]

Comment: Awesome Pointer no 3 is what did it for me.